# Performing an SQL "dry run" (from Go application)

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb

I have a tool in Go which generates SQL scripts from a YAML file. To minimize the risk that the generated scripts will fail I'd like to do something like a "dry run", either by means of SQL or the Go application.

My first thought was using the `ROLLBACK` statement but then the generated script would also include a rollback instead of a commit.

Does SQL or Go provide something like this?

Comment: Not sure about mariadb and mysql, but when using postgres with the lib/pq driver you can create prepared statements from query strings, and if the query contains invalid sql, or even if its valid but you specify a table/column that does not exist [Prepare](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) will return an error. Note that if you choose to go this route make sure to Close each prepared statement if you don't intend to reuse later.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered running the 'Dry Run' statements inside of a transaction, provided by the `*DB.Conn`?

```
db, err = sql.Open(...)

txn, err = db.BeginTx(...)
defer txn.Rollback

rows, err = txn.Query(...)
```

Comment: Good point. This way I could also make use of a data source in my IDE. And if the statements complete I could write it to a file.